# Problema de transparência usando position fixed em css

Tags: php, html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando criar um menu que não se mova independente da rolagem do usuário na página usando `position fixed`.

Porém estou tendo um problema com a transparência, sempre que o menu encontra com outro conteúdo, ele fica transparente.

Antes eu usava um menu com `position absolute`, e o menu nem aparentava ter transparência. Pesquisei no google tentei algumas coisas mas não consegui resolver, cheguei a colocar `opacity: 100%` mas também não resolveu.

Segue o código css do meu menu, e imagens demonstrando o que ocorre. Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

```
div#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(60,60,65,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
div#menu ul
{
    text-align: left;
}
div#menu li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}
div#menu a
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
div#menu a:hover
{
    color: rgba(50,50,255,1);
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa definir o z-index nesse caso (quando menor mais acima) [link w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Coloquei z-index: 1; e funcionou mesmo, eu ainda não conhecia o z-index, muito obrigado pela ajuda.